# Enable and verify TLS 1.2 for Stand Alone Java Application using JDK 1.7

Tags: ssl, network-programming, apache-axis, tls1.2, jdk1.7

I don't have much exposure on Networking concepts and I was asked to upgrade current TLSv1 version to TLSv1.2 for a stand alone java application (which do not use any web/application server). And currently we are using JDK 1.7 for this application.

**Application Info:**

This is a SOAP based webservice application developed using Axis-2. We created a client stub and making calls to external service outside our organization.

**Tried the following option**

I've added the following System property to my start-up script.

SYSPROPS="${SYSPROPS} -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"

**I've the following questions:** 

1) Is this the right way to unable TLsv1.2? 
2) If yes, how to verify if the TLSv1.2 is really upgraded to TLSv1.2?

I'm struggling to implement this for 3-4 days but couldn't get this done. Any thoughts/suggestions please..

Comment: You should not have been asked. This is a five minute job. Strange employer, to give you this assignment and then wait 3-4 days without intervening.

Comment: @EJP
Pardon my ignorance. I'm newbie to Axis2 and web services. 
In my application, i'm using Axis2-generated Service Stub. I read somewhere that "https.protocol" will only affect connections made through use of the HttpsURLConnection class. 
Seems like I need to modify the Axis2-generated Service Stub but I couldn't understand what and where I need to make the changes. 
Please help me with this. Thank you.